# Any open source software to automate installation process of web applications on hosting services?

Tags: open-source, cloud-service, web-server

Some hosting services offer automatic installation for popular web application such as Wordpress, Discourse and so on. (for example, you can check [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com), [BitNami](http://bitnami.com), etc.) which allow users to install applications easily on their purchased space.

Is there any such open source app to automate installation on barebones servers via some click by users?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the second question. You want to host this Open Source software on Heroku?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, Nope! something to found a cloud hosting service. However It's migrated to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11910/7810 now!

Comment: Not open source, but [related](http://www.simplescripts.com/).

Comment: Bounty or not, this question is really broad. Can you give more details about the intended users of the end system? Can you give more requirements (preferably prioritized or in MSCW style) about what you need from the software you're looking for?

Comment: Have you used the Ubuntu Software Centre, synaptic or Gnome Software? Do any of those meet your needs? If not, which additional features do you need?  https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/ http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/synaptic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Software

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) is what you're looking for.

You install `WebMatrix` on your system or server. Then you can search the gallery and download and install **almost-any** open source portal with only some few clicks.

The amazing point of `WebMatrix` is that in addition to .NET-based portals, you can also download and instal PHP-based CMSes (WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but as a starting building block you could have a system that creates and runs Ubuntu virtual machines.

Ubuntu is great because it has packages for most web apps like phpBB, MediaWiki, Alfresco, OpenBravo, etc.

You would still have to create a VM management system and a web interface, though.