# Something to create a cloud hosting service?

Tags: open-source, cloud-storage

Is there any open source software for founding a cloud hosting service such as [Heroku](http://heroku.com), [Pagoda Box](http://pagodabox.com), AWS, etc.?

Requirement:

- Awesome interface
- Marketing system alongside Scalable features: de/increasing space, Ram, Cpu, etc by user
- User Profile

In summary, something to manage hardware resources and users!

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: By "found" do you mean "start a company that offers a service"?  Maybe http://www.openstack.org/ ?

Comment: Heroku and AWS are very different services. (Indeed I think Heroku is hosted on AWS.) So the answer is 'yes' there is open source software, but questions need to be much more precise in describing which part of the problem they want to solve.

Comment: Is this correct: Openstack is equivalent for AWS and Openshift is equvalent for heroku?, In summery, I want to start for (invest on) a company that offers a cloud service as in Heroku!

Answer (score 1):

While not quite the same as AWS, I believe [red hat's OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/installing-enterprise-paas-part-1) is pretty close, and it is open source, and allows you to run it on your own servers (private cloud as they call it)

I can't say I have created my own private cloud with it yet, but AFAIK it's the only actual option for this type of application that is free/open source.